# Determining XAML parse error locations on CE

Tags: c++, parsing, xaml, windows-ce, silverlight-embedded

We're evaluating using Silverlight on C++ for an embedded project and are prototyping some screens for a demonstration.

What I'm finding is that Expression Blend will create XAML files that work fine on the desktop but, when porting them over to the CE device results in parse errors (apparently not all tags and elements are supported on CE).

I'm looking for a way to determine where the parse error is occurring, rather than manually removing line by line and then attribute by attribute to determine the offending segment.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight Embedded under Windows CE 6 R3 supports XAML 2.0 (that is Silverlight 2.0) syntax and elements.

You can use the function in [this post](http://shaihi.blogspot.com/2010/01/silverlight-error-codes-in-string.html) to translate the error message - it includes all the Silverlight error codes.

Comment: I got the error code, but it wouldn't tell me the offending tag.  A lot of HTML parsers will give you a line/column of the offending tag.

Comment: Have you been debugging this for 2 years now?